# How to add a class to Inception Model (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, raspberry-pi

I'm building an object recognition application in real time on a raspberry Pi, so I decided to use tensorflow to doing so. 
Google’s Inception v3 model is a great with object recognition but it's terrible with detecting persons, so I am thinking of adding a class "Persons" to the other 1000 existing classes of Inception.
So "Transfer Learning" isn't gonna help me because it deletes the other classes.

Have you an idea guys!!!
Thank you